# php ГПСЧ mt_rand()

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Назрел ещё один вопрос, как можно восстановить seed для mt_srand(), который использовался для генерации чисел с помощью mt_rand()? Сами числа известны, нужно по ним подобрать seed.

Comment: Ровно также как и для любого другого генератора: проверять каждый сид. Но для MT это может не сработать.

Comment: Какова максимальная длина сида в mt_srand()? 2^32? Или число может быть и 2^60 например?

Comment: А вы не пробовали сначала посмотреть на алгоритм сами?

Comment: Алгоритм мне не известен, но похож на алгоритм mt_rand(). Так как с увеличением сида, получается находить числа со списка больше вместе с самым первым. Чисел много, если так подсчитать по увеличению сида, то для всех чисел сид будет длиной примерно 30 может даже больше, перебрать не реально циклом.

Comment: А зачем Вам нужно восстановить seed? Чтобы подставить его в mt_srand() и с помощью mt_rand() заново получить последовательность псевдослучайных чисел, которая Вам уже и так  известна?

Comment: Что-то типо того, только набор чисел разный, я хочу узнать сид для каждого и посмотреть какой между ними интервал, и на основе данных генерировать новые числа.

Answer (score 0):

1. Если у Вас имеется последовательность псевдослучайных чисел, сгенерированная именно mt_rand, то Вы можете попробовать перебрать все возможные варианты сида. Если имеющаяся у Вас последовательность псевдослучайных чисел достаточно длинная, и mt_rand не использует какой-нибудь сторонний источник энтропии к введённому сиду, то можно однозначно восстановить использованный сид.
2. Если алгоритм генерации имеющихся у Вас чисел не известен, то, очевидно, необходимо восстановить не только какой-то сид, но и сам алгоритм генерации.
   Ответ на то, как это сделать, был дан в [другом Вашем вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/715396/php-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB).
3. Последовательность чисел может быть слишком короткой, или для её генерации мог использоваться криптографически стойкий генератор псевдослучайных чисел, либо она вообще могла быть сгенерирована аппаратным генератором случайных чисел, а следовательно, подбор генератора и сида, которыми была сгенерирована имеющаяся у Вас последовательность чисел может быть очень сложным.

Определитесь, что конкретно Вам необходимо? Найти именно тот генератор и сид, которыми была сгенерированна имеющаяся у Вас последовательность чисел, либо сконструировать свой собственный генератор, который бы при некотором сиде выдавал некоторую конкретную последовательность чисел?

Comment: А если к примеру последовательность не из mt_rand(), можно ли будет восстановить её с помощью подобранного сида в mt_ rand()? И какое максимальное значение сида в mt_srand()?

Comment: @user262975, Функция `mt_srand()` требует в качестве аргумента значение типа `int`. Возможно, максимальные и минимальные значения можно узнать с помощью констант `PHP_INT_MAX` и `PHP_INT_MIN`. Так как количество возможных различных сидов конечно, то и количество возможных числовых последовательностей, выдаваемых генератором также конечно. Вполне возможно, что какая-то из них совпадает с Вашей, однако, также возможно, что никакая из них не совпадает с Вашей.

Comment: Значение PHP_INT_MAX = 2147483647. Может ли сид для mt_srand() быть больше этого числа? И будут ли другие выдавать числа после этого сида, или же будут повторяться старые?

Comment: @user262975, Нет, не может.

Comment: Могу точно сказать, что генерировались числа на perl.